# remove curly brackets from saved txt file from python code

Tags: python, csv, text

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import urllib2
import json
import time
from datetime import datetime

while 1:
        api_key = 'VtxgIC2UnhfUmXe_pBksov7-lguAQMZD'
        url = 'http://www.energyhive.com/mobile_proxy/getCurrentValuesSummary?token='+api_key
        response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
        content = response.read()

        for x in json.loads(content):
                if x["cid"] == ("PWER"):
                    pwer=(x["data"][0].values()[0])
        for x in json.loads(content):
                if x["cid"] == "PWER_GAC":
                    pwer_gac=(x["data"][0].values()[0])
        for x in json.loads(content):
                if x["cid"] == "PWER_IMM":
                    pwer_imm=(x["data"][0].values()[0])
        for x in json.loads(content):
                if x["cid"] == "FBAK_IMM":
                    fbak_imm=(x["data"][0].values()[0])

        power = pwer,pwer_gac,pwer_imm,fbak_imm

        make_str = str(power) 

        print( ", ".join( repr(e) for e in power ) )
        savefile=open('wattsonBD.txt','a')
        savefile.write(make_str)
        savefile.write('\n')
        savefile.close()

        time.sleep(5)
```

In the line

```
savefile.write(make_str)
```

i have tried to remove the curly brackets from the saved text document with no luck, i have managed to remove them from the print line

```
print( ", ".join( repr(e) for e in power ) )
```

Comment: Why are you loading the exact same JSON, and iterating over it, four separate times?

Comment: its picking four values of data.

Comment: But why not do that in the same iteration?

Comment: i'm completely new to coding, last time writing code was 30 yrs ago on a commodore VIC 20

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no curly brackets in the output of this code. If you're talking about *round* brackets, also known as *parentheses*, then the best way to remove them from the file is to never write them in the first place.

Your code stores the four values in a *tuple*, and then you generate `make_str` by converting that tuple into a string. Tuples, when presented as strings, have parentheses around them. That's just how Python works.

You've already demonstrated that you know how to format values *without* parentheses in your `print` command:

```
print( ", ".join( repr(e) for e in power ) )
```

Instead of (or in addition to) printing the value, store that value in `make_str`:

```
make_str = ", ".join(repr(e) for e in power)
```

Continue to write `make_str` to your file, and you'll get the four values without parentheses.

Comment: at the moment it's guess work and lots of youtube video's, going to get a good book for the holidays. i will try to put  <br/>`make_str = ", ".join(repr(e) for e in power)<br/>into my code.